# get the return value from facebook comment meta

Tags: php, facebook, variables

I want to get the number of comment on my blog post, and I have two method that I can get it to be display.

First one is the one I'm currently using, but it cause some problem with the function `file_get_contents` where there will be an error after a while.

and this is the whole function

```
<?php function fb_comment_count($url)
{
  $json = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=' . $url));
  return ($json->$url->comments) ? $json->$url->comments : 0;
}
?>
```

So the above code works fine no problem, but as I have mention there will be an error after a while.

I have found another way which is a good one, and never got an error

```
<fb:comments-count href='<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>'></fb:comments-count>
```

But what I want is to assign the number that is being display to a variable so that I can use it for some validation and to display something later, but I can't do it.

```
<?php echo $number_of_comment = "<fb:comments-count href='<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>'></fb:comments-count>"; ?>
```

Nothing is being display in the `echo` from variable `$number_of_comment`

Any suggestion?

---

UPDATE:

So this was the error that I'm talking about

> failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, nevermind now this is the way to get it assign to the variable

```
<?php echo $number_of_comment = "<fb:comments-count href=" . get_permalink($post->ID) . " ></fb:comments-count>"; ?>
```